# Running commandLine after configuration Phase will cause an issue in future version of gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am working on gradle script where I am getting the revision of hg repository and then using that revision to tag the repository with below tasks which is working fine.My concern is I am triggering the commandline after configuration phase and this could create a problem in future version of gradle. Is there any other way to do these task?

```
task hgRev(type: Exec, dependsOn: UpdateRepo) {
    commandLine 'hg', 'id', '-i', "${project.rootDir}"
    standardOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    ext.hash = {
        return standardOutput.toString()
    }
}

task tagHg(type:Exec, dependsOn: hgRev) {
    doLast {
        if (execResult.exitValue == 0) {
            project.logger.info("Succesfully Created the tag \"Build $cbversion\"")
        } else {
            project.logger.info("It failed.Please check the Bamboo logs for the reason")
        }
    }
    doFirst {
        def hash = tasks.hgRev.hash()
        commandLine 'hg', 'tag', '-r', "$hash", "Build $cbversion"

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use exec blocks and the execute() method instead of Exec tasks, that will make many things easier:

```
// simple method, not a task
def hgRev() {
    def hashStdOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'hg', 'id', '-i', "${project.rootDir}"
        standardOutput = hashStdOut
    }
    return hashStdOut.toString().replaceAll('\\+', '').trim()
} 

task tagHg(dependsOn: UpdateRepo) {
    doLast {
        def hash = hgRev()

        def cmd = ["hg", "tag", "-r", hash, "Build $cbversion"]
        def sout = new StringBuilder(), serr = new StringBuilder()

        Process proc = cmd.execute()
        proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
        proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
        println "out> $sout err> $serr"

        if (proc.exitValue() == 0) {
            project.logger.info("Succesfully Created the tag ")
        } else {
            project.logger.info("It failed.Please check the Bamboo logs for the reason")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: when I run this command it fails def exitValue = "hg tag -r $hash Build $cbversion".execute() so I simply tried "hg tag -r $hash Build $cbversion".execute() which is working but with one problem using Build prefix before version.I need to run this on both os windows and linux

Comment: I changed hgRev() to remove '+' and trim(). Also changed tagHg task to properly use Process API and print more debug info. Also put tag name 'Build ...' in hyphens.

Comment: this still doesn't tag properly Added tag 'Build, 2.1.9' for changeset .It is adding the single quotes and , after Build prefix

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with StringBuilder?If I see the tag then there are two tags one is Build and other is 1.1.1